# 5 Card Poker Hand JAVA-Analyze and Categorize

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Prompt: Write a program that reads five cards from the user, then analyzes the cards and prints out the category of hand that they represent.

Poker hands are categorized according to the following labels: Straight flush, four of a kind, full house, flush, straight, three of a kind, two pairs, pair, high card.

I currently have my program set as follows, first prompting the user for 5 cards, 2-9, then sorting the cards in ascending order. I set up my program to prompt the user and then go through several if else statements calling methods. I am having issues though where its not identifying three or four of a kind.

Example, if I enter 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, it identifies it as TWO PAIRS instead of Three of a Kind.
Same for entering 1, 1,1, 1, 4, it identifies as three of kind instead of 4.

Any suggestions to my code?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  final int HAND_SIZE = 5;    
  int[] hand = new int[HAND_SIZE];

  getHand(hand); //Prompt user for hand

  sortHand(hand);//Sort hand in ascending order

  if(containsFullHouse(hand))
  {
         System.out.print("FULL HOUSE!");
  }
  else if(containsStraight(hand))
  {
         System.out.print("STRAIGHT!");
  }
  else if(containsFourOfAKind(hand))
  {
         System.out.print("FOUR OF A KIND!");
  }
  else if(containsThreeOfAKind(hand))
  {
         System.out.println("THREE OF A KIND!");
  }
  else if(containsTwoPair(hand))
  {
         System.out.println("TWO PAIRS!");
  }
  else if(containsPair(hand))
  {
         System.out.println("PAIR!");
  }
  else
         System.out.println("High Card!");
}


public static void getHand(int[] hand)
{
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
  System.out.println("Enter five numeric cards, 2-9, no face cards please");

      for(int index = 0; index < hand.length; index++)
      {
         System.out.print("Card " + (index + 1) + ": ");
         hand[index] = input.nextInt();
      }   
}

public static void sortHand(int[] hand)
{
  int startScan, index, minIndex, minValue;

  for(startScan = 0; startScan < (hand.length-1); startScan++)
  {
         minIndex = startScan;
         minValue = hand[startScan];
         for(index = startScan + 1; index <hand.length; index++)
         {
                if(hand[index] < minValue)
                {
                       minValue = hand[index];
                       minIndex = index;
                }
         }
         hand[minIndex] = hand[startScan];
         hand[startScan] = minValue;
   }
}

public static boolean containsPair(int hand[])
{
  boolean pairFound = false;
  int pairCount = 0;
  int startCheck = hand[0];

  for(int index = 1; index < hand.length; index++)
  {
         if((hand[index] - startCheck) == 0)
         {
                pairCount++;
         }
         startCheck = hand[index];
  }

  if (pairCount == 1)
  {
         pairFound = true;
  }
  else if(pairCount !=1)
  {
         pairFound = false;
  }
  return pairFound;             
}


public static boolean containsTwoPair(int hand[])
{
  boolean twoPairFound = false;
  int twoPairCount = 0;
  int startCheck = hand[0];

  for(int index = 1; index < hand.length; index++)
  {
     if((hand[index] - startCheck) == 0)
         {
            twoPairCount++;
         }       
     startCheck = hand[index];
  }  

  if (twoPairCount == 2)
  {
         twoPairFound = true;
  }
  else if(twoPairCount != 2)
  {
     twoPairFound = false;
  }

  return twoPairFound; 
}

public static boolean containsThreeOfAKind(int hand[])
{
  boolean threeFound = false;
  int threeKind = 0;
  int startCheck = hand[0];

  for(int index = 1; index < hand.length; index++)
  {
         if((hand[index] - startCheck) == 0)
         {
                threeKind++;
         }
         startCheck = hand[index];
  }   

      if(threeKind == 3)
      {
             threeFound = true;
      }
      else if(threeKind !=3)
      {
             threeFound = false;
      }
     return threeFound;
}

public static boolean containsStraight(int hand[])
{
   boolean straightFound = false;
   int straight = 0;
   int startCheck = hand[0];

   for(int index = 1; index < hand.length; index++)
   {
      if((hand[index] - startCheck) == 1)  
          {
                 straight++;
          }
          startCheck = hand[index];
   }   

   if(straight == 4)
   {
      straightFound = true;
   }       
   return straightFound;
}

public static boolean containsFullHouse(int hand[])
{
  boolean fullHouseFound = false;
  int pairCheck = 0;
  int startPairCheck = hand[0];

  for(int index = 1; index < hand.length; index++)
  {
         if((hand[index] - startPairCheck) == 0)
         {
               pairCheck++;
         }
         startPairCheck = hand[index];

  }

  int threeOfKindCheck = 0;
  int startThreeKindCheck = hand[0];

  for(int index = 1; index < hand.length; index++)
  {
         if((hand[index] - startThreeKindCheck) == 0)
         {
               threeOfKindCheck++;
         }
         startThreeKindCheck = hand[index];
  }

      if(pairCheck == 1 && startThreeKindCheck == 3)
      {
         fullHouseFound = true;       
      }       
  return fullHouseFound;
}


public static boolean containsFourOfAKind(int hand[])
{
   boolean fourFound = false;
   int fourKind = 0;
   int startCheck = hand[0];

   for(int index = 1; index < hand.length; index++)
   {
          if((hand[index] - startCheck) == 0)
          {
             fourKind++;
          }
          startCheck = hand[index];
   }   

   if(fourKind == 1)
   {
          fourFound = true;
   }
   else if(fourKind !=4)
   {
          fourFound = false;
   }
      return fourFound;
 }
}
```

Comment: Please make your question better by showing your best good faith attempt at a solution to your *one* single question, and use this to make the question much more specific. Also please go through the [help] and [ask] sections to see how to best use this site.

Comment: Have made progress updating as we speak.

Comment: Then you *might* want to [edit] and improve your question soon as it already has 3 out of the needed 5 votes to close it.

Comment: Made adjustments and provided the full code, wondering why its categorizing three of a kind as two pairs and four of a kind as three...

Comment: Here is my implementation of the same task: https://github.com/brotherla/PokerHandAnalyzer/blob/master/PokerHandAnalyzer/src/com/lwg/poker/HandCategoryAnalyzer.java

Answer (score 0):

Some hints.

Start with the highest hand. This eliminates lots of logic.

I.e if you check for pairs first, than you also have to check to make sure that your pair is the only pair, and not three of a kind.

But if you already ruled all of those out your code would be check card 1and2 23 34 and 45.